# Python: How to Capture WebPage as Image File?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, image-processing

I want to cache a webpage as an image upon a user request, but I don't know where to start with this.

I'm developing on App Engine with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a web service such as [thumbalizr](http://thumbalizr.com/) since a lot of the programs for this type of thing aren't always install-able on appengine (because they use C++, etc).  Other options include [girafa](http://www.girafa.com/) and [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/).

Comment: Thumbalizr looks very interesting, though it is pretty slow.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good library for capturing a webpage as a png image:

http://github.com/AdamN/python-webkit2png

Comment: Can webkit2png be installed on App Engine?

Comment: I've never worked with App Engine, so I'm not sure of its limitations. Hopefully someone else will jump in here.

Comment: I doubt it, I believe webkit2png requires the webkit headers and such which would (very) likely not be available on the app engine. A web service is probably the best choice.

Comment: Does it use any c-libraries, app engine only supports native python.

Comment: also, it requires a X server running.

Answer (score 0):

There are websites that to this for you. Google is your friend. If you build a script around them, you have what you need. As a demonstration, see http://webshots.velocitysc.com/sandbox/.
There are also downloadable programs that do it, such as the one at http://download.cnet.com/Advanced-Website-to-Image-JPG-BMP-Converter-Free/3000-2094_4-10900902.html. These are just examples; google a while and you'll find better implementations.

If you want to do it yourself, you basically need to duplicate a web browser (the HTML rendering part, anyway), which is unrealistic, or use a preexisting rendering engine like webkit as Zach suggests. If I were you, I would forget about doing it myself and use a preexisting web service, unless this is going to be the core of your application.